# Erro no método ToString("C3")

Tags: c#

Fiz isso no construtor de minha classe e agora dá erro dizendo que não há  sobrecarga para o método ToString com 1 argumento. Estava funcionando, dei um clean na solution e pifou tudo.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {

                //string userName = null;
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoDTO, Liberacao>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Juros,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Juros.ToString("C3")
                        ));
            });
```

Comment: sua propriedade Juros é Nullable<float>?

Comment: Que tipo é essa propriedade Juros?

Comment: double? Mas estava funcionando, aí eu dei um clean na solution e não funcionou mais

Comment: Removi o nulo(double) e não deu mais o erro.

Comment: O que é dar um Clean na solution?

Answer (score 1):

A questão é que Nullable herda diretamente da classe `object`, e object não possui um ToString() que aceite uma string. Para você fazer o uso do ToString() com um parametro que aceite formatação você teria que utilizar:

```
opt.MapFrom(src => Juros.Value.ToString("C3")
```

Pois quando eu chamo a propriedade `Value` do Nullable, ele me da o primitivo decimal que herda diretamente da classe `ValueType`, que possui o seu ToString(string format). Ainda vale ressaltar que meu exemplo ira dar uma exceção caso meu Juros seja nulo. Valide o nulo.

Answer (score 0):

A questão era o seguinte. Dava o erro, porque o campo era setado como `Nullable<double>`, assim:

```
public double? Juros { get; set; }
```

Tirei o `?`(nullable) e deu certo.